# Google drive API Permission to check domain level share permission

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am using the [Permissions: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/get) endpoint to check if the user has permission the document.

while i am using this endpoint i came across strange behaviour. it was like this as i need to find out if a given user has permission to edit a given document.

1)  if the document directly shared edit permission for that user the above endpoint gives me the correct permission object.

2) if the document is shared with the domain privileges (Anyone at  who has the link can edit) . In this case every time it gives me a error response.

My view in this case in the google document view even its the domain level share permission or user level share permission the user get the correct set of workflow. But to check these permission levels from the API endpoints does not works as expected.

Is this a known issue? Is their a another way to check the file permission if it shared under the domain level?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that there is some missing information (i.e. error message, code snippet, screenshots etc.), I'll make an attempt to answer your question here :)

To check for the file permission, it can be achieved in the following ways:

1. via Drive API

   - The [Permissions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/get) resource would be ideal for checking the
     permission for a user or domain. You may also try using the
     [Permissions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list), which would lists all file's permissions.
2. Google Drive UI

   - Right click on the file, select "Share..."
   - Click Advanced

With that being said, I noticed in my testing, if the file (doc) is shared under the domain level and you are not performing this under the same domain, both the view and API resource will return an error response. I suggest making sure when you're calling through the API you're using the appropriate domain user. Hope this helps and Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The `Permissions.Get` operation can tell if you a file was shared directly to a user, but it can't tell you if a user has access to the file via a `group` permission, `domain` permission, or `anyone` permission.

Using a `Permissions.List` operation you might be able to tell if the file is shared to anyone or if it's shared to the user's domain (based on, for example, the user's email address).